# Inferred type is not general enough in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a program that takes in a list of elements (such list must take both integers and fractional numbers) and gives a list of *cut* sums:

- first element of resulting list is the sum of the whole list
- second is the sum of list without head
- third is the sum of the list without head and second element
- and so on.

My result so far is:

```
cuttingSum :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
cuttingSum l = 
 let         
  cuttingSum_iter [] res = reverse (res)
  cuttingSum_iter ll res =
  cuttingSum_iter (tail ll) ((foldl (+) 0 ll) :: res)
 in
  cuttingSum_iter l []


main = do
 print $ cuttingSum [1,2,3]
```

I'm getting error:

```
 ERROR "task9-02-1.hs":5 - Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : foldl (+) 0 ll
*** Expected type : a
*** Inferred type : _26
```

I'm using Hugs as it's the task requirement, but ghci also shows some sort of similar error. What's the problem?

Comment: Did you mean `:: res` there?  That indicates the type, maybe you meant `: res` meaning prepend onto the list `res`?

Comment: Oh, yes, still writing in StandardML style. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it did. Seems to work fine now

Comment: I'm half-tempted to vote to close this question as "simple typographical error", but on the other hand this seems like a non-obvious consequence of a typo, so I think it's worth keeping - @bheklilr if you agree, could you turn the comment into an answer?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I agree, the small typo leads to a completely unrelated compiler error.  I'll add an answer explaining it and make it a community wiki.

Comment: While you're obviously welcome to make it community wiki if you choose, I don't see any particular reason to. You diagnosed the problem so should get the reputation, and there's not likely to be much need for other people to enhance the answer.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam It doesn't seem like it took enough effort to be deserving of an actual answer, but having something that shows up on google to explain what the error might be would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is simply a typo, you have `foldl (+) 0 ll :: res` instead of `foldl (+) 0 ll : res`, with only one `:`.  This is because `::` indicates the *type* of an expression.  When you have

```
cuttingSum_iter ll res = cuttingSum (tail ll) ((foldl (+) 0 ll) :: res)
```

This is equivalent to

```
cuttingSum_iter ll res = cuttingSum (tail ll) ((foldl (+) 0 ll) :: b)
```

Because `res` as an argument and `res` as a type live in different namespaces.  In the type namespace, any identifier beginning with a lower case letter is a *type variable*, and as we know the name of a variable doesn't matter to the compiler, only to the programmer.  **From this point, I'll refer to it as `b` to avoid confusion with the `res` argument.**

Since you're telling the compiler that the expression `foldl (+) 0 ll` has the type `b`, it fails the type checking stage.  The compiler can figure out that `ll` is at least a list, and using it in `foldl (+) 0` means that it must contain `Num` elements, so `foldl (+) 0 ll` must have type `Num a => a`.  This does not match with the type `b`, since `b` does not have the `Num` constraint.  This is what leads to the error message you see of

```
ERROR "task9-02-1.hs":5 - Inferred type is not general enough
```

The inferred type is not general enough because the inferred type has the `Num` constraint.

In GHC, you'd instead get the error

```
Couldn't match type ‘t’ with ‘res’
  because type variable ‘res’ would escape its scope
This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
  an expression type signature: res
  at <interactive>:13:57-79
Expected type: [res]
  Actual type: [t]
Relevant bindings include
  ll :: [t] (bound at <interactive>:13:21)
  cuttingSum_iter :: [t] -> [a] -> [a] (bound at <interactive>:12:5)
In the third argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘ll’
In the second argument of ‘cuttingSum_iter’, namely
  ‘((foldl (+) 0 ll) :: res)’
```

To me, this one is a little more clear since it mentions the "type variable `res`" on the second line, and says it expected it to have `[res]` while expecting the type `[t]` where `cuttingSum_iter` has the type `[t] -> [a] -> [a]`.  Seeing that it mentions "type variable `res`" and "Expected type: `[res]`", this at least points a little more towards what the problem was, although it still isn't immediately clear what is actually the problem.